Как сделать счетчик нажатий с прогресс баром и лимитом нажатий?
вот здесь нажали на картинку 6 284 раза, линия почти заполнена а на второй картинке нажали 6302 раза, border и background заполнились чуть больше. Вторую картинку вставить не получается.


let count = 0;

function clickButton() {
  count++;
  document.getElementById("counter").innerText = count + "/10";

  if (count >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("countButton").disabled = true;
  }
}
#countButton {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}
   <div class="gold">
         <button id="countButton" onclick="clickButton()"<a href=""><img src="IMG_3948.PNG" alt="Image 4"></a></button>
         <p id="counter">0/10</p>
 </div>



Нужно добавить к картинке с верхнего левого края счетчик нажатий всего нажатий максимум может быть 100, пример оформления текста: 0/100, каждый раз когда человек будет нажимать на картинку то рамки текста закругленные на 20 пикселей будут понемногу заполнять рамки border цветом: #f3a45d, и одновременно background к примеру цветом: белый, и цифры тоже будут меняться как в примере кода, то есть одно нажатие ровняется 1% заполнения цветом border и background, после достижения лимита в 100 нажатий, на картинку больше нельзя будет нажать, заполнение цветом с лево на право.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

@Grundy Без проблем, сейчас добавлю

Есть несколько вариантов запомнить данные для последующего вывода и взаимодействия. Но, основываясь на вашей разметке и пожеланиях в комментариях и чате, могу предложить сохранять прогресс голосования в локальном хранилище - работа с ним немного понятнее и проще. (Здесь лишь демонстрационный пример учёта голосов и шкалы заполнения. Чтобы использовать сохранение и вывод после обновления страницы, раскомментируйте некоторые участки кода и запустите там, где поддерживается localStorage.)


const LS = /*JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counters')) ||*/ {counters:{}};

[...document.querySelectorAll('.picture > img')].forEach((image) => {
  let counter = LS?.counters[image.src];
  if (counter === undefined) {
    LS.counters[image.src] = {count: 0, limit: +(image.dataset['limit'].replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))};
    image.dataset['count'] = 0;
    image.dataset['limit'] = LS.counters[image.src].limit;
  }
  image.addEventListener('click', fCountInc);
  image.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
});

function fCountInc(ev) {
  let counter = this.nextElementSibling;
  let current = LS.counters[this.src];
  if (current.count < current.limit && ev.isTrusted) this.dataset['count'] = current.count += 1;
  if (current.count == current.limit) counter.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  counter.style.setProperty('--progress', 100 / current.limit * current.count + '%');
  counter.textContent = `${current.count.toLocaleString('ru-RU')}／${current.limit.toLocaleString('ru-RU')}`;
  /*localStorage.counters = JSON.stringify(LS);*/
}
body { margin: 0; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-content: center; gap: .25em; min-height: 100vh; background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #17171f, #5a2429) no-repeat; }
.picture {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.picture > img {
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.picture > .counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: .5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .25em;
  border: 3px solid #0000;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  color: #ddd;
  background: 50% 50% / cover linear-gradient(#16141a 0 0) padding-box, 0 0 / var(--progress, 0) 100% linear-gradient(#fc0 0 0) border-box no-repeat, 50% 50% / cover linear-gradient(#1c1a22 0 0) border-box, #0000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.picture > .counter[disabled] {
  color: #444;
  background:  #fc0;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
<figure class="picture">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/MraLT.jpg" data-limit="10" alt="red wall">
  <p class="counter"></p>
</figure>
<figure class="picture">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/VxVNC.jpg" data-limit="25" alt="yellow flower">
  <p class="counter"></p>
</figure>
<figure class="picture">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/A9VLC.jpg" data-limit="1000" alt="green forest">
  <p class="counter"></p>
</figure>
<figure class="picture">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/oYG0R.jpg" data-limit="1000000" alt="blue rose">
  <p class="counter"></p>
</figure>



Если возникнут вопросы, то задайте их в комментариях к этому ответу.

Для решения можно использовать подход с двумя элементами

заполненный
незаполненный

Расположив их один поверх другого, изменяя ширину можно добиться эффекта прогресса
Например


let count = 0;

function clickButton() {
  count++;
  document.getElementById("counter").innerText = count + "/10";
  progress.style.width = (count * 10) + '%'; // меняем ширину прогресса, в данном случае в процентах.

  if (count >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("countButton").disabled = true;
  }
}

filled.style.width = counter.offsetWidth + 'px'; // выставляем дублирующему элементу ширину такую же как в основном счетчике
#countButton {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#counter {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#filled {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#progress {
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .2s linear;
}
<div class="gold">
  <button id="countButton" onclick="clickButton()">Add</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- счетчик с неактивным бордером -->
    <p id="counter">0/10</p>
    <div id="progress"> <!-- элемент отвечающий за прогресс -->
      <p id="filled">&nbsp;</p><!-- элемент дублирующий основной счетчик -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Очень благодарен вам, это именно то что мне было нужно, спасибо вам большое! у меня появился вопрос, если я захочу сменить значение нажатий к примеру на 100 или больше, что мне придется изменить в вашем коде?

@мояличнаяжизнь, смотри комментарии в коде - там есть "изменение прогресса" - в этом месте тебе нужно правильно рассчитать на сколько процентов должно быть заполнено

уже разобрался, есть еще вопрос, возможно сделать так что бы все количество нажатий после перезагрузки страницы сохранилось для всех пользователей?

Зайдите в чат пожалуйста
